# Grammar Preview feature no longer working in Comma IDE CP (paid version)

Tags: raku, commaide

I recently upgraded to v 2022.05 of Comma IDE (Complete Edition), Build #CP-221.5591.1, built on May 26, 2022

I can no longer get the Grammar Viewer to show on a project that it used to work in. I click on Tools -> "Preview Raku Grammar" and nothing happens. The Grammar Preview window does not appear and there are no errors.

Running this version of rakudo on a mac (Intel chip):

Welcome to Rakudo™ v2022.03.
Implementing the Raku® Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2022.03.

Also tried 2022.06 version of Rakudo and it doesn't work with this version either.

Comment: Aiui, best Comma help process is: ① Post SO with [MRE] and sysinfo (OS and IntelliJ). ② Post on IRC w/ SO link. ③ Email info@commaide.com w/ SO link. ④ Initial responses may or may not include ones from Comma team. Most issues are ones on non-Linux systems. (Per the Comma team's experience, Apple are worst for this though IntelliJ are no slouches.) ⑤ There's a weekly wave of attention to all things in the Raku world with Liz's RWN. ⑥ The Comma team do a monthly review as part of their monthly release cycle. ⑦ If an SO isn't fixed in a following Comma release, maybe restart the cycle at step ②.

Comment: Please report this in the subscriber feedback application on the Comma website. It's probably undetected fallout from this release making the (more painful than usual) migration to the latest IntelliJ platform version.